# How to put a numpy array in a specific position of another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am doing linear interpolation and the formula is y = y0 + (x - x0) * ((y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0)). My points are

```
    a = np.array([[9, 0],
     [11, 7],
     [18, 14],
     [38, 31],
     [43, 36],
     [67, 59]])
```

For example: let's take x0 = 18, y0 = 14, x1 = 38, y1 = 31. So for every value of x between 18 and 38 I have to get the y values. Then I need to put those pairs between the [18, 14] and [38, 31] in the array.

This will be done for all the pairs in the `a`. I mean the pairs between [9, 0] & [11, 7] will be inserted between [9, 0] & [11, 7], similarly the pairs between [11, 7] & [18, 14] will be inserted between [11, 7] & [18, 14] and so on.

I have implemented the following code which calculates the pairs fine but I couldn't manage to insert the way that I have described above.

```
    import numpy as np
    
    a = np.array([[9, 0],
     [11, 7],
     [18, 14],
     [38, 31],
     [43, 36],
     [67, 59]])
    c = a.copy()
    
    result = np.array([])
    
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        r = np.array([])
        for j in range(a[i, 0] + 1, a[i + 1, 0]):
            y = round(a[i, 1] + (j - a[i, 0]) * ((a[i + 1, 1] - a[i, 1])/(a[i + 1, 0] - a[i, 0])))
            r = np.append(j, y)
        result = np.insert(c, [i+1], r, axis=0)
    
    print(result.astype(int))
```

The expected output should be:

```
    [[9, 0],
     [10, 4],
     [11, 7],
     [12, 8],
     [13, 9],
     [14, 10],
    ...
     [18, 14],
     [19, 15],
    ...
     [38, 31],
    ...
     [43, 36],
    ...
     [67, 59]]
```

I hope my explanation makes sense. Any help regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `np.interp`.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an item in an array its a little time consuming task. Every time you insert an item in a certain position all the items after has to be moved by one step. So potentially this operation could be `O(n^2)`.

You could insert the items at the end (so no previous item in the array has to be moved, and the only operation needed in some cases is making the array bigger). Then at the end when all your points are in the array you just sort them by the `x`, which is an `O(n*log(n))` operation.

You can sort the points using:

```py
a = np.sort(a, axis=0)
```